# python discord bot event not working

Tags: python, discord.py

My distance calculator event is not working.
It should ( if working ) calculate the distance between 2 places and give a message on how long the player should wait untill he go's there ( pokemon go related )
Not given me errors it just does nothing.
i tryed different things but none seem to work.
Anyone can help me out ? Would be great !

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import gpxpy.geo
import math
import asyncio

client = discord.Client(command_prefix='kaikai*')

@client.async_event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as:")
    print(client.user.name)
    print("ID:")
    print(client.user.id)
    print("Ready to use!")

@client.async_event
async def on_message(message) :
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    elif message.content.startswith("kaikai*test") :
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "BOT READY!")

@client.async_event
class Distance:
    """Calculate the distance between two coordinates."""
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def distance(self, ctx, *, message):
        """Calculate the distance between two coordinates and also provide you with a cooldown time."""
        # Your code will go here

        def error_embed_1(self):
            embed=discord.Embed(
                title="Error:",
                description="Not enough data given. Did you give 4 different coordinates, seperated by spaces?",
                color=0x207cee)

            return embed
        def error_embed_2(self):
            embed=discord.Embed(
                title="Error:",
                description="Your message is invalid. Please use this format\n``!distance <num1> <num2> <num3> <num4>``\nWhich would look like this: ``!distance 51.301597 -0.598019 51.270664 -0.594132``",
                color=0x207cee)
            return embed

        def calc_embed(msg, msg2):
            embed=discord.Embed(
                title="",
                description=" ",
                color=0x207cee)
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Calculated Distance:**",
                value="{} Kilometers".format(msg),
                inline=False)
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Cooldown Timer:**",
                value="{} ".format(msg2),
                inline=False)
            return embed

        def calculate(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
            dist = gpxpy.geo.haversine_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
            dist = dist/1000
            dist = round(dist, 2)

            return dist

        def cooldown(dist):
            time = " "


            if dist >= 1500:
                time = "120 minutes"

            elif dist >= 1403 and dist <= 1500:
                time = "120 minutes"

            elif dist >= 1344 and dist <= 1403:
                time = "119 minutes"

            elif dist >= 1300 and dist <= 1344:
                time = "117 minutes"

            elif dist >= 1221 and dist <= 1300:
                time = "112 minutes"

            elif dist >= 1180 and dist <= 1221:
                time = "109 minutes"

            elif dist >= 1020 and dist <= 1180:
                time = "101 minutes"

            elif dist >= 1007 and dist <= 1020:
                time = "97 minutes"

            elif dist >= 948 and dist <= 1007:
                time = "94 minutes"

            elif dist >= 897 and dist <= 948:
                time = "90 minutes"

            elif dist >= 839 and dist <= 897:
                time = "88 minutes"

            elif dist >= 802 and dist <= 839:
                time = "83 minutes"

            elif dist >= 751 and dist <= 802:
                time = "81 minutes"

            elif dist >= 700 and dist <= 751:
                time = "76 minutes"

            elif dist >= 650 and dist <= 700:
                time = "73 minutes"

            elif dist >= 600 and dist <= 650:
                time = "69 minutes"

            elif dist >= 550 and dist <= 600:
                time = "65 minutes"

            elif dist >= 500 and dist <= 550:
                time = "61 minutes"

            elif dist >= 450 and dist <= 500:
                time = "58 minutes"

            elif dist >= 400 and dist <= 450:
                time = "54 minutes"

            elif dist >= 350 and dist <= 400:
                time = "49 minutes"

            elif dist >= 328 and dist <= 350:
                time = "48 minutes"

            elif dist >= 300 and dist <= 328:
                time = "46 minutes"

            elif dist >= 250 and dist <= 300:
                time = "41 minutes"

            elif dist >= 201 and dist <= 250:
                time = "36 minutes"

            elif dist >= 175 and dist <= 201:
                time = "33 minutes"

            elif dist >= 150 and dist <= 175:
                time = "31 minutes"

            elif dist >= 125 and dist <= 150:
                time = "28 minutes"

            elif dist >= 100 and dist <= 125:
                time = "26 minutes"

            elif dist >= 90 and dist <= 100:
                time = "24 minutes"

            elif dist >= 80 and dist <= 90:
                time = "23 minutes"

            elif dist >= 70 and dist <= 80:
                time = "22 minutes"

            elif dist >= 60 and dist <= 70:
                time = "21 minutes"

            elif dist >= 50 and dist <= 60:
                time = "20 minutes"

            elif dist >= 45 and dist <= 50:
                time = "19 minutes"

            elif dist >= 40 and dist <= 45:
                time = "18 minutes"

            elif dist >= 35 and dist <= 40:
                time = "17 minutes"

            elif dist >= 30 and dist <= 35:
                time = "16 minutes"

            elif dist >= 25 and dist <= 30:
                time = "14 minutes"

            elif dist >= 20 and dist <= 25:
                time = "11 minutes"

            elif dist >= 15 and dist <= 20:
                time = "8 minutes"

            elif dist >= 10 and dist <= 15:
                time = "6 minutes"

            elif dist >= 8 and dist <= 10:
                time = "4 minutes"

            elif dist >= 5 and dist <= 8:
                time = "3 minutes"

            elif dist >= 4 and dist <= 5:
                time = "2 minutes"

            elif dist >= 3 and dist <= 4:
                time = "2 minutes"

            elif dist >= 2 and dist <= 3:
                time = "1 minutes"

            elif dist and dist <= 1:
                time = "48 seconds"

            return time

        bool = True
        List = str(message)
        var = List.split(" ")
        try:
            lat1 = float(var[0])
            long1 = float(var[1])

            lat2 = float(var[2])
            long2 = float(var[3])

        except IndexError:
            msg = error_embed_1(self)
            bool = False
        except ValueError:
            msg = error_embed_2(self)
            bool = False

        if bool == True:
            calc = calculate(long1, lat1, long2, lat2)
            cooldown = cooldown(calc)
            msg = calc_embed(calc, cooldown)
        await client.send(embed=msg)


client.run("mytokenhere")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing all the `@client.async_event` to `@client.event`. You can see in the example [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/basic_bot.py) that this is the correct usage.

Since you have an `on_message` event, you will have to specify that commands have to be processed. This is done by calling `process_commands(message)` inside the `on_message` event. This is not done by default. Documentation for the `async` branch is [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working), while for the rewrite branch it's [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working).

The `Distance` class that you create is also not loaded (as far as I can tell, please correct me if I am wrong). I suggest moving this to a separate file, then loading it in your main bot file. Below is an example of how this can be done, where `bot.py` is the main file that runs the bot and `cog.py` contains an example class with an `add` command. `bot.py` also includes the `on_message` event with `process_commands(message)` to illustrate it's usage.

**bot.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

client.load_extension('cog')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client ready')

@client.command()
async def ping():
    await client.say('Pong')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'Hello'
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Hello')

    await client.process_commands(message)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

**cog.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

class TestCog:

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.counter = 0

    @commands.command()
    async def add(self):
        self.counter += 1
        await self.bot.say('Counter is now %d' % self.counter)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))
```